# Install second gcc on the server

Tags: linux, gcc, centos

I have centos server on which 4.8.2 gcc is installed.Now I want to install 4.8.5 gcc on same server. The requirement is I need two gcc on same server. How can I proceed to install 4.8.5 gcc on server?

Comment: Check out [How to install multiple versions of GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#multiple) from GCC FAQ.

Comment: You can have as many versions of gcc as you want, installed at the same time. .. As long as program suffix and a hidden location is used. Please see this example https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fcqkMS_nitdLFG0PgWwb6cvlFr5UwPRf/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using environment modules: http://modules.sourceforge.net

On our systems we have quite a few compilers installed and can switch between them quite easily via commands similar to: `module add gcc/6.2.0`.

The general setup our administrators provided consists of:

1. A couple directories containing the module files, which are text files containing the directives required to change the relevant shell search paths. (/sw/RedHat-7-x86_64/common/modules, for example)
2. Corresponding directories into which the actual software is installed. (/sw/RedHat-7-x86_64/common/local)

The directories are organized by software/version.  Thus for the case of gcc/6.2.0, the module file is comprised of:

```
#%Module 1.0
module add gmp/6.1.1
module add mpfr/3.1.4
module add mpc/1.0.3
module add ppl/1.2
module add cloog/0.18.4
module add dejagnu/1.6
module add autogen/5.18.7
module add isl/0.16.1

prepend-path PATH /opt/local/stow/gcc-6.2.0/bin
prepend-path MANPATH /opt/local/stow/gcc-6.2.0/share/man
prepend-path CPATH  /opt/local/stow/gcc-6.2.0/include
prepend-path LIBRARY_PATH /opt/local/stow/gcc-6.2.0/lib64:/opt/local/stow/gcc-6.2.0/lib
prepend-path LD_RUN_PATH /opt/local/stow/gcc-6.2.0/lib64:/opt/local/stow/gcc-6.2.0/lib
prepend-path LD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/local/stow/gcc-6.2.0/lib64:/opt/local/stow/gcc-6.2.0/lib
```

There are also module files for gmp and friends and each of those software packages was installed using a configure/cmake/whatever invocation which included an install prefix of /opt/local/stow/$package.  (In the case of gcc/6.2.0, this invocation was something along the lines of: `./configure --prefix=/opt/local/stow/gcc-6.2.0`)

It is possible to make the module files quite elaborate; thus we have some which automatically detect the executable directories, libraries, manual/info pages, headers, pkgconfig directives, python virtual environments, etc.  Here is an example for a python package living in its own virtual environment:

```
#%Module
set NAME [module-info name]
set MODULE_FILE_AUTHOR "bob"
set MODULE_FILE_AUTHOR_EMAIL "bob@gmail.com"
set MODULE_FILE_MAINTAINER "bob@gmail.com"
module-whatis "labnote: Make a lab notebook!"

if [ module-info mode load ] {
 if {! [info exists ::env(MODULE_PRE)] } {
  setenv COMMON "/cbcb/sw/RedHat-7-x86_64/common"
  setenv MODULE_PRE "$::env(COMMON)/local"
 }
}
set DIR $::env(MODULE_PRE)/[module-info name]
### Add pre-requisites here
module add Python3/common/3.6.0
### Add extra variables here
### Define a simple help message
proc ModulesHelp { } {
  global NAME  MODULE_FILE_AUTHOR MODULE_FILE_AUTHOR_EMAIL MODULE_FILE_MAINTAINER
  puts "The $NAME module file was installed by $MODULE_FILE_AUTHOR ($MODULE_FILE_AUTHOR_EMAIL)
  and is maintained by $MODULE_FILE_MAINTAINER."
}
set is_module_rm [module-info mode remove]
###
# Add your executable to PATH.
###
if { [file isdirectory $DIR/bin] == 1} {
 prepend-path PATH $DIR/bin
}
###
# Add an include directory
###
if { [file isdirectory $DIR/include] == 1} {
 prepend-path CPATH $DIR/include
}
###
# Set up library paths
###
if { [file isdirectory $DIR/lib] == 1} {
 prepend-path LIBRARY_PATH $DIR/lib
 prepend-path LD_RUN_PATH $DIR/lib
}
###
# Python virtual environments
###
if { [file isfile $DIR/bin/activate] == 1} {
 setenv VIRTUAL_ENV $DIR
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use Docker. Any other way would probably be quite painful (unless CentOS has some facility for that). You may try this container https://hub.docker.com/r/ryccoo/gcc-4.8/tags/ , but it's not specified what version it is.

Here's the dockerfile Dockerfile for 4.8, maybe you'd manage to make it use 4.8.5: https://github.com/bincrafters/docker-centos-gcc48-i386/blob/master/Dockerfile

If none of those works, just get container with some OS which has package for this version and install it. Remember that you need further steps to save state of image. I hope you don't have to compile it. Compiling GCC sucks unless you have right toolchain.

Remember that containers are not persistent, so the directory with the sources have to be attached separetely. The command line for compiling them would be something like that:

```
docker run -u root -it -v /local/path/to/source:/mounting/point/in/container --rm  \
    name-of-container:version -w /mounting/point/in/container /bin/bash -c \
    "make clean && make; chown -R 1000:1000 ."
```